# What type of tests should I use for writing a test with TDD?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, testing, tdd

I come from a PHP (Laravel) background and have just switched to Python. I am a big fan of TDD and have previously been writing 'feature' tests. Now I am writing AWS Lambdas (which are making lots of 3rd part API calls), I'm not really sure what type of tests to write? Should I switch to unit tests?

Now I don't have a database what should I be asserting? I think I can only mock the API calls and check that they have been called and that the correct parameters have been passed to them?

Any recommended reading?

Answer (score 0):

There are two important ideas for designing handler functions for AWS Lambda

1. Because Lambda doesn't give us a lot of control over the initialization of our handler, we aren't going to invest in automated mistake detectors for "the" handler.  Instead, the handler that AWS knows about will normally delegate work to some object which has been configured to use live clients

   ```
   # Code not covered by automated mistake detectors
   # You'll use other techniques to catch errors here.
   dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")

   the_delegate = create_delegate(dynamodb)

   def the_handler_aws_knows_about(event, context):
       return the_delegate.do_some_work(event, context)
   ```

   To create cost effective tests for the logic in the delegate, we can start with something like

   ```
   # inert_dyanmodb_client could be a general purpose mock
   # a general purpose spy, or even a legitimate implementation
   # of the dynamodb client api with telemetry built into it.

   test_delegate = create_delegate(inert_dynamodb_client)
   test_delegate.do_some_work(test_event, test_context)

   # assert the implementation satisfies the specification for this case
   ```

   [The Doctrine of Useful Objects](http://docs.eventide-project.org/user-guide/useful-objects.html) talks more about the inert substitute idea in more general contexts.
2. When trying to detect errors in your implementation, an important question to ask is "Will this information be important to us in our production environment?"  AWS Lambda is transient compute - so if there is information that you need, you need an implementation that copies that information somewhere else; for example cloudwatch, or some open telemetry host.

   In that case, designing your cloudwatch/telemetry client so that it caches the information that it shares means that you can leverage the cached information in your tests

   ```
   test_delegate = create_delegate(inert_dynamodb_client, cloudwatch_telemetry)
   test_delegate.do_some_work(test_event, test_context)

   # naive example for demonstration purposes
   assert 3 == cloudwatch_telemetry.how_many_times_did_we_log_dynamodb_calls()
   ```

> I think I can only mock the API calls and check that they have been called and that the correct parameters have been passed to them?

The idea of separating complicated things and hard to test things works at a lot of different scales.  For example, when I'm writing code for a `dynamodb.put_item` call, there's a lot more risk that the item will be wrong in some subtle way than there is risk that I'll get the parameters wrong in some subtle way.

That usually means I'll create the item using a testable implementation, and then evaluate the risk of the put_item call separately.